# Print function causes ArcMap to hang

Tags: arcgis-desktop, printing

ArcMap hangs after clicking on print.  I get the dreaded spining globe icon as if it is working, but does nothing.  I eventually go to task manager to end the task.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?
http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/2080

Comment: I never print anything from ArcMap. I just find it much easier to export to a PDF and print that. That's just sort of my way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I am not saying this will fix the problem for sure, but, here are a few lessons learned by me as far as printing from ArcMap.

First, I frequently was having problems with it either never finishing a print job as you describe or giving a memory full error message.  I finally got with tech support on it (this was back in v9.3.1 days fyi) and they said it was a known issue at the time for large maps that you're trying to print, especially if you're trying to print at very high resolutions and/or with high resolution imagery/raster data in the map.  This can significantly run up memory cost quickly and so running a full defrag (assuming you're not using a SSD hard drive) on your machine is highly recommended if you're having issues with larger maps.  Also, try doing a full defrag and re-boot the machine and try printing before opening anything else up to check if it's a memory issue via process of elimination.  (That's what tech support had me do and it actually worked to resolve most of my print issues).

Second, if you run the AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe utility (C:\Program Files (x86)>ArcGIS>Desktop10._>Utilities>AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe) and go to the Print/Export tab, there is a setting for Temporary metafile size limit:  If it is too small, from the way it's been explained to me, it can create a situation where it endlessly tries to create the print output but there isn't enough memory to complete the request and it hangs the program.  Again, this same type problem was experienced multiple times by me and since changing that setting and scheduling regular defrags on my machine, I haven't had any issues exporting or printing like that.

Third, as noted in the comments above, a printing directly from ArcMap can be rather risky and error/issue prone sometimes and so I would recommend exporting all maps to PDF  and then printing from that PDF file.  Not only does the export process often give you a bit more information along the bottom status/notice bar of the application as it runs, but it also reduced the number of miss-prints from vector lines and polygons "magically" getting redrawn throughout the map on the final print (though they haven't moved in the MXD on screen) as sometimes occurs when printing directly from ArcMap in my personal experience.

Ok, so, like I said, that may or may not solve your printing problem, there are too many possibilities of what it might be.  Hopefully though that at least gives you some starting points to check on.  Hope it helps, let me know if you need clarification though.